# git: merging commits from remote repository into subtree following renaming

Tags: git, git-subtree

So I've used git subtree strategy to incorporate a repository branch into another as a subdirectory.
First I used `git subtree add -P some/dir1 myremote dev`.
Then I renamed the subtree directory to `some/dir2`. That was a mistake, since renaming seems to break git's knowledge of the subtree integration, and now I can't use `git subtree` commands to merge remote changes, and other subtree-related operations won't take into account the commits preceding the rename.

The `newrepo` branch:

```
(create subtree some/dir1 from remote/C0) - C1 - (rename some/dir1 some/dir2) - C2 - HEAD
```

Here C1 and C2 stand in for a number of commits.
The `oldrepo` from which the subtree was created:

```
C0 -- C1 - HEAD
```

The remote branch from `oldrepo` contains a number of commits since the initial incorporation into `newrepo`.
If these were branches in the same repository:

```
(oldrepo) C0 - C1 ------------------------------------ HEAD
(newrepo)  \ 
            D0 - D1 - (rename some/dir1 some/dir2) - D2 - HEAD
```

(here D0 is the commit generated by the initial `git subtree add` operation, so it corresponds to C0. If this were branches in the same repo, C0 and D0 would be the same commit.)
Now, `git subtree pull -P some/dir2 oldrepo dev` fails because of unrelated histories.

Is there some way to merge changes from `oldrepo` into the `newrepo` subtree, considering all commits since the initial incorporation, both before and after the rename?

Basically, is there a way to tell git that D0 is a common ancestor to the commits from `oldrepo`, and that the rename of the subtree directory doesn't affect the commits from oldrepo?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the code with me since I changed employer, but I remember editing manually the file where subtree info is kept along with a folder change. That could have prevented things going wrong when you renamed at first. Maybe it can help patching it?

Comment: Do you know what file that is?

Comment: If you run `git subtree` in the same way as you did originally, on the same original repository, it *should* generate the same series of commits, so that any new commits should add on as related history. There have been reports of bugs in git subtree though, and it's poorly maintained.

Comment: @CharlesLanglois Unfortunately no, but you could try a grep with the folder name or remote address and you should find it. Bonne chance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to solve this situation.
First, by branching out from the commit before the rename occurred.
Then using `git subtree pull ...`(which now understood the existing subtree).
Then merging the main branch into the new branch, thus adding the remaining commits, from the renaming commit until the head of `newrepo/main`.
Everything worked out smoothly, with minimal conflicts, as the renaming was understood by git and applied to new files from new commits.
Finally, I merged back the temporary branch into main.

```
  
(newrepo/main) D0 ----------M3 (HEAD)
                \           /
(newrepo/temp)   M1-------M2

D0: (commit before renaming)
M1: (git subtree pull --squash -P some/dir1 oldrepo dev) 
M2: (git merge main)
M3: (git merge temp)
```